# WPF Problem with TreeList Control Expanding Beyond UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like the TreeListControl to be docked within the window so that it never extends beyond the window area.

[Here we have an example of how the TreeList control extends beyond the window area. I would like it to end at the window's edge, and the scrollbar to be only within the TreeListControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHvSu.png)

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle" TargetType="dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                <Setter Property="ToggleSwitchHeight" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="ToggleSwitchWidth" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4E00BE"/>
                <Setter Property="ShowBorder" Value="True"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AccountingTurnoversCardIndexTopPluginViewModel}">
            <plugins:AccountingTurnoversCardIndexTopPluginView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem x:Key="DecimalSummaryItem" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="RemarkGridCellDataTemplate">
            <Image Height="16">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="Niezgodność sumy obrotów syntetyki z sumą analityk">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource MismatchIcon}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Niezgodność sumy obrotów syntetyki z sumą analityk"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
        <dxmvvm:ObjectToObjectConverter x:Key="RemarkToIconConverter">
            <dxmvvm:MapItem Source="Niezgodność sumy obrotów syntetyki z sumą analityk" Target="{StaticResource MismatchIcon}" />
        </dxmvvm:ObjectToObjectConverter>
        <dxmvvm:ObjectToObjectConverter x:Key="RemarkToTooltipConverter">
            <dxmvvm:MapItem Source="Niezgodność sumy obrotów syntetyki z sumą analityk" Target="Niezgodność sumy obrotów syntetyki z sumą analityk" />
        </dxmvvm:ObjectToObjectConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <!--<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--Sekcja przycisków i linii poziomej-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,5">
                <controls:CommandButtonsGroup ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}" 
                                              Focusable="False"
                                              BindableProperiesSet="{Binding ElementName=treeListControl}" />
                </TextBlock>
                <Rectangle Style="{DynamicResource Rectangle.HorizontalLine.Dark}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Margin="0,2"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            </StackPanel>


            <!--TopToolbar-->
            <plugins:AccountingTurnoversCardIndexTopPluginView DataContext="{Binding TopPlugin}"  Grid.Row="1"/>

            <!--Layout-->
            <DockPanel 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Background="{DynamicResource {dxgt:TableViewThemeKey ResourceKey=SearchPanelBackground}}"
            DataContext="{Binding}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit 
                    x:Name="UseRowIndentToggle"
                    IsChecked="{Binding UseRowIndent, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    AllowUpdateTwoWayBoundPropertiesOnSynchronization="True"
                    CheckedStateContent="Wyłącz wcięcia wierszy"
                    UncheckedStateContent="Włącz wcięcia wierszy"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    Margin="5"
                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle}">
                    </dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit>

                    <dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit 
                    x:Name="ShowFilterRowToggle"
                    IsChecked="{Binding ShowAutoFilterRow, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    CheckedStateContent="Ukryj wiersz filtrowania"
                    UncheckedStateContent="Pokaż wiersz filtrowania"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="5"
                    Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle}">
                    </dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" x:Name="TreeListGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <!--Kontrolka treeList-->
                <dxg:TreeListControl Name="treeListControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Row" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=TreeListGrid, Path=ActualHeight}">
                    <!--Definicja kolumn-->
                    <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
                        <!-- Kolumny widoczne -->
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Account" Header="Konto" UnboundType="String" Fixed="Left" Width="130" ShowInColumnChooser="False">
                        </dxg:TreeListColumn>
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="AccountName" Header="Skrót konta" UnboundType="String" Width="200" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DebitOpeningBalance" Header="BO Wn" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CreditOpeningBalance" Header="BO Ma" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DebitAmount" Header="Obroty Wn" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CreditAmount" Header="Obroty Ma" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DebitAmountYTD" Header="Obroty Wn n." UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CreditAmountYTD" Header="Obroty Ma n." UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="DebitBalance" Header="Saldo Wn" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CreditBalance" Header="Saldo Ma" UnboundType="Decimal" Width="130" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Remark" Header="Uwagi" UnboundType="String" Width="60">
                            <dxg:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image
                                Width="15"
                                Height="15"
                                Source="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource RemarkToIconConverter}}"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource RemarkToTooltipConverter}}"
                               />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxg:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dxg:TreeListColumn>
                        <!-- Kolumny niewidoczne -->
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Id" Header="Identyfikator" UnboundType="Integer"  ShowInColumnChooser="False" AllowSearchPanel="False" Visible="False" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="IsOffBalanceAccount" Header="CzyPozabilansowe" UnboundType="Boolean" ShowInColumnChooser="False" AllowSearchPanel="False" Visible="False" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort0" Header="Sort0" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="0" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort1" Header="Sort1" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="1" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort2" Header="Sort2" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="2" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort3" Header="Sort3" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="3" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort4" Header="Sort4" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="4" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Sort5" Header="Sort5" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="5" />
                        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Id" Header="Identyfikator zapisu" UnboundType="Integer" AllowSearchPanel="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" Visible="False" SortOrder="Ascending" SortIndex="6" />
                    </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
                    <!--Podsumowania kolumn-->
                    <dxg:TreeListControl.TotalSummary>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="DebitOpeningBalance" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="CreditOpeningBalance" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="DebitAmount" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="CreditAmount" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="DebitAmountYTD" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="CreditAmountYTD" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="DebitBalance" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                        <dxg:TreeListSummaryItem SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="N2" FieldName="CreditBalance" CalculationMode="Mixed"/>
                    </dxg:TreeListControl.TotalSummary>
                    <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                        <dxg:TreeListView 
                    Name="treeListView" 
                    AllowEditing="False" 
                    TreeDerivationMode="ChildNodesSelector" 
                    TotalSummaryPosition="Bottom" 
                    NavigationStyle="Row" 
                    ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                    ShowIndicator="False" 
                    RowIndent="{Binding RowIndentValue}"
                    ShowAutoFilterRow="{Binding ShowAutoFilterRow}"
                    ShowCriteriaInAutoFilterRow="True"
                    ShowExpandButtons="True"
                    PrintExpandButtons="True">
                            <dxg:TreeListView.AutoFilterRowCellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="dxg:FilterCellContentPresenter">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.AutoFilterValue, Converter={dxmvvm:ObjectToBooleanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </dxg:TreeListView.AutoFilterRowCellStyle>
                        </dxg:TreeListView>
                    </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                </dxg:TreeListControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I would like the TreeListControl to be docked within the window so that it never extends beyond the window area.